# ListView RenderSectionHeader Will not properly render with a json get or less than 9

Tags: listview, react-native

I am new to React-Native and I am building a small App. I have run into an odd problem. If my JSON length, is greater than 9 my section Header does not work properly. I am basically doing a show and hide. I have a floating button, that when pressed hides and in it's place shows a input box.  When I exceed the length of 9 the section header, does not force another rendering. I could manipulate the data, but I feel like I would cheat myself out of a learning experience. Hopefully, I have explained myself clearly.

My Json data looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": "0",
    "service": "Haircut"
}, {
    "id": "1",
    "service": "Brian"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "service": "Cut&Shave"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "service": "Beard Trim"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "service": "Senior Citizen Haircut"
}, {
    "id": "5",
    "service": "Crew Cut"
}, {
    "id": "6",
    "service": "Fade"
}, {
    "id": "7",
    "service": "Line Up"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "service": "Kids Cut"
}, {
    "id": "9",
    "service": "Long Hair Cut"
}]
```

I setup my constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      damping: 1 - 0.6,
      tension: 400,
      dataBlob: [],
    dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}),
     showInput:false
    };

  }
```

My API call is here:

```
componentDidMount() {

    fetch('http://54.152.253.14/barbershop/appointmentHelper.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.state.dataBlob = this.state.dataBlob.concat(responseData);
      console.log(responseData);
      this.setState({
          dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.dataBlob),
          isLoading: false,
        });
    })
    .done();
  }
   My RenderSectionHeader is:

  renderSectionHeader(){
    console.log('render Section called');
  if(this.state.showInput){
    return (
      <View style={styles.section}>
       <Header headerText='Wills Barbershop'/>
       <Input onSubmitEditing={(event)=>this.editServices(event)}
      placeholder={'Enter a new service'}
        />
      </View>
      )
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.section}>
       <Header headerText='Wills Barbershop'/>
      <FloatingButton onPress={() => this.showInput()}>
      </FloatingButton>
      </View>
    )

  }
```

Here is where I set state and would except a new rendering:

```
  showInput(){
 console.log('show Input');
  this.setState({
    showInput:!this.state.showInput,
  })
}
```

My ListView is here:

```
renderList = (dataObj,sectionID,rowId) => {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Row damping={this.state.damping} tension={this.state.tension} onPress={()=>this.deleteItem(rowId)}>
          <View style={styles.rowContent}>
            <View style={styles.rowIcon} />
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.rowTitle}>{dataObj.service}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.rowSubtitle}>Drag the row left and right</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Row>



      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
           <ListView
           renderSectionHeader={() => this.renderSectionHeader()}
            key={this.state.dataBlob}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(data, sectionID, rowID) => this.renderList(data, sectionID, rowID)}
            style={styles.listView}
            renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
            />
           );
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be a bit hackish. but have you thought about forcing an update in your showInput by manipulating your datablob ?

Comment: Thank you but still having trouble. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can someone help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you're running into an issue here is because you're not using `renderSectionHeader` correctly. Your data isn't broken into sections, it's just a single large piece of data (which is totally fine). I think you would be better off adjusting your render logic so that the typical render logic can be run in React Native (rather than also checking inside of the ListView).

Doing so would leave you with the following - you may have to make appropriate style changes but the concept is the same.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      {this.renderSectionHeader()}
      <ListView
        key={this.state.dataBlob}
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(data, sectionID, rowID) => this.renderList(data, sectionID, rowID)}
        style={styles.listView}
        renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Hope that works for you!